# Is natural projection a natural transformation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Given a group $G$ and its normal subgroup $N$, there is a **natural projection** $\pi: G\to G/N,\ g\mapsto gN$.

**Question:** Is 'natural projection' a kind of natural transformation?

I know determinant is a natural transformation between $GL_n(-)$ and $(-)^*$, the functors $\bf\text{CRing} \to \bf\text{Grp}$. There is also a natural transformation between the identity functor of $\bf\text{Grp}$ and the factor-commutator functor $(-)/[-,-]$. However, I can't figure out which functors the 'natural projection' relates to.

I have just begun learning category theory in order to gain a better understanding to some concepts in algebra, and I'm totally unfamiliar with the common techniques in category theory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It’s a natural transformation between the functors $G$ and $G/N$, whose source is the category whose

- objects are pairs $(G, N)$ consisting of a group and a normal subgroup, and whose
- morphisms are commutative squares.

The target is the category of groups.

Comment: How are morphisms commutative squares?

Comment: @CommutativeAlgebraStudent: a normal subgroup is in particular a morphism $N \to G$, and a morphism $(N_1, G_1) \to (N_2, G_2)$ is then a commutative square relating them (the additional data is a pair of morphisms $n : N_1 \to N_2, g : G_1 \to G_2$ compatible with the two inclusions $N_1 \hookrightarrow G_1, N_2 \hookrightarrow G_2$).